# How to fix this character in a string "’". Not working with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

In mysql table, i have data having this character `’`.
Like: 
`Francesca’s Baker`

But when i use `json_encode` it gives null instead of the string. The problem i have found is with this character `’` or similar special characters.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Convert text to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<?php

$data=array("test"=>utf8_encode("Francesca’s Baker"));

echo json_encode($data);
```

Returns `{"test":"Francesca\u0092s Baker"}`

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is eliminating the `’` character, instead of replacing it with normal apostrophe. How to do that?

Comment: and when i use your code, then it gives me this `{"test":"Francesca\u00e2\u0080\u0099s Baker"}`

Comment: What editor are you using? You might need to encode your editor in utf8 as well. http://puu.sh/3dCje.png

Comment: You could also represent the single quote as `&#8217;` in HTML. Where you are loading this information is important as well. You might also want to add `<meta charset='utf-8'>` in your head.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes may throw errors randomly, it gets really annoying!!!
You need to escape the single quote!
There are two solutions to your problem.

Solution 1:
Replace all `'` with `\'`
 `str_replace("\'","\\\'",$string);`
This will replace `'` with `\'` from the string $string.

Solution 2:

```
$newstring = htmlentities($string);
```

This will change any special characters in the string `$string` to html entities, so when the string `$newstring` is printed to the screen it will look normal.
If you need further help, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem to capture json and I solved with

```
$data = array(
    'result' => utf8_encode($xxx),
);

echo json_encode($data);
```